# numberpad is randomly turned on

Tags: keyboard

I am running ubuntuGnome on an ASUS vivobook S301-LA. A column of 4 keys on the keyboard (which is a normal French AZERTY keyboard) changes the keys of 0pm! and instead types /*-+.

It switches (gets turned on) at seemingly random times, sometimes mid sentence, ever since switching from xubuntu to ubuntuGnome.

It looks like the characters normally seen on the number pad (which my computer shouldn't have), but the buttons get turned on somehow, but I am not sure what would normally turn them off.

Holding the Fn key displays the normal character.

This appears to happen for both 14.04.4 and 16.04.1, but did not happen on xubuntu.

The neighbouring characters do not display numbers, just the four ones with the symbols.

What normally activates or disables the number pad?

Thanks!